# Symfony in subfolder of DocumentRoot doesn't include RewriteBase

Tags: .htaccess, symfony, mod-rewrite

I have a weird situation with Symfony 3.2.6. The whole code is above `public_html` directory which is a DocumentRoot.
In `public_html` I have a directory called `panel`. In this directory I have put `app.php` and `app_dev.php` controllers with `.htaccess`. I have setup properly `require` and i`nclude_once` paths.
The problem is that when I run `mydomain.com/panel/app_dev.php` I get an error:

> No route found for "GET /panel/app_dev.php"

So it seams that this code in `.htaccess` doesn't work properly for this situation.

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}::$1 ^(/.+)/(.*)::\2$
RewriteRule ^(.*) - [E=BASE:%1]
```

So I have commented out this and used this after `RewriteEngine On`

```
RewriteBase /panel/
```

but this gives the same result. Anyone knows how to fix it?